# Do article pages need to have an RSS Feed page?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, technical-seo, rss, feeds

I am working on a blog software. This blog has a home page, category pages and articles.

I will add an RSS feed to this blog. I added the RSS feed to the home page by adding `/feed` to the end of the url. So `example.com/feed.xml`

Category pages all have the same logic, for example `example.com/seo/feed.xml` each category has an rss feed page.

But I can't decide if the article pages, i.e. the content, has an RSS feed or not. I checked some website and most of them don't.

I can't decide which one is right. Do you think every article should have an RSS feed page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the way you have it set up is good. You want an RSS feed for all posts and then another for each category. The reason for this is that people subscribe to them - they'll either be interested in following your whole site or the category that interests them. Search Engines may also use an RSS feed as one method to discover content.